# Disable saving network credentials Windows 8

Tags: network-share, windows-8, credentials

We're having 3 Workstations running Windows 8 with network access to our internal LAN. They're not member of the domain to ensure access control.
When a user now tries to access a network share, he is prompted to enter credentials. So far, this is the desired behavior.
But now the windows explorer saves the credentials for later use, which is not wanted.
Because we never intendet to use these Win8 computers as part of the domain network, they are the home editions. So it's not possible to disable this by editing security policies.
How can I achieve windows 8 not saving the network credentials still allowing users to log on network shares?

Comment: Why do you not want the network credentials saved?

Comment: These are "public" computers, meaning every client/visitor could use them quite freely. So access to our files in the network should not be allowed without authentication.

Comment: In that case, perhaps [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/670874/disable-remember-my-credentials-on-windows-7-home-premium) can help you?

Comment: other regedit solutions did not work, but this one helps. thanks a lot for pointing that one out

Answer (score 0):

In my case the first answer [in this post](http://HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE%5CSYSTEM%5C%20CurrentControlSet%20%5CControl%5CLsa%5Cdisabledomaincreds) solved my problem.

> Set the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ CurrentControlSet \Control\Lsa\disabledomaincreds` to 1.

Comment: Edited your answer, feel free to roll back if you dislike it.